# Layout weigth não funciona Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou querendo deixar meus `<button/>` e `<ImageButton/>` com o mesmo tamanho "mesmo peso" mas o comando `android:layout_weight="1"` não funciona assim deixando o tamanho de cada um diferentes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"


tools:context="com.example.tulio.exercicio3.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RGM:XXXX"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fulann"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp" />


<Button
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
  android:onClick="principal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:text="Principal" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/auto"
    android:onClick="automoveis"
    android:text="Automoveis" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/portateis"
    android:onClick="portateis"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Portáties" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:src="@drawable/empresarial"
    android:text="Empresarial"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:text="Residencial"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:src="@drawable/residencial"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:text="Viagem"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:src="@drawable/travel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Então, tipo... tenta colcar um valor fracionário, por exemplo 5 botões = 1/5 = 0.20... 6 botões = 1/6 = 0,16667... e assim por diante entendeu 
?

Comment: ou use uma GridLayout que seus problemas ficarão  com o tamanho ficarão resolvidos, pois dai voce ajusta o span, altura, largura etc da grid e todos os componentes ficarão dentro das colunas e linhas dessa grid

Answer (score 3):

Isto acontece porque você especificou um tamanho para cada `View`. Basicamente, quando você atribui um peso para uma `View` você não pode atribuir um tamanho a ele, ou seja, se você quer que o `width` ou `height` tenha um peso, **o valor de cada um destes precisa ser igual a 0**.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

No caso acima você quer que a altura tenha um peso, então ela precisa ser 0. Se fosse com a largura, esta seria **zero**.

Faça isto em todos os outros e seu problema será solucionado.